# WPML - Stop language redirection in initial load

Tags: plugins, multi-language, plugin-wpml

We have a multilingual website which is connected with English & Arabic using WPML plugin in WordPress. As a default behavior, the website is redirecting to /en/ version which I need to stop, but the same time, /en/ should not be removed from any menu links. The overall expectation is to stop the redirection only in initial load.

For an example: If I type www.abcd.com, currently it redirects to www.abcd.com/en/ that needs to be stopped. I tried couple of workarounds advised in [WPML forum](https://wpml.org/forums/topic/disable-redirection-from-com-to-com-en/) but no luck.

Thanks in advance for any help/suggestion.

Comment: Hi There, I was able to fix the issue by changing WPML settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution provided in [WPML forum](https://wpml.org/forums/topic/stop-language-redirection-en-in-initial-load/).